# for loop with different types c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which i need to loop over different kinds of arrays, the first one is `map<string,vector<string>>` and the second is an `integer` array.

to implement this i did :

```
struct {map<string,vector<string>>::iterator it; int i; } s;
int k = 0;
for ( s.it = m.begin(), s.i = 0; s.it != m.end(), s.i < size; s.i+=2)
{
    while (k != integer_array[s.i] && k < size)
    {
            s.it++;
        k++;
    }       
    if (k == integer_array[s.i])
    {
        cout << s.it.first << endl; // this line does not complie       
        k = 0;
            s.it = m.begin();
    }
}
```

explain of what i'm trying to do:
integer_array stores indexes and i'm trying to print the map value at index which stored in integer_array.
any suggestions?

Comment: Do you encounter some problems with current approach?

Comment: I guess `// this line is not complies` means "this line does not compile". If I'm right, could you give us the error message from the compiler?

Comment: With the comma, you ignore the first condition completely. You have to logically combine your conditions (probably `&&` is what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is in the iterator.

Instead of:

```
    cout << s.it.first << endl;
```

Try:

```
    cout << s.it->first << endl;
```

The reason is that a STL iterator behaves like a pointer: if you want to access the value pointed, then you must dereference your iterator (either through operator * or through operator ->).

In the current case, the pointed value is a std::pair of std::string and std::vector, and you want to print the first std::string. Thus, you need to write `it->first`.

Comment: Then you can choose my answer as "the right answer"... :-)